# Inner Join: Mysql prints more lines than available (same multiple rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, rows

I have to tables (`hmmscan1` and `arath_scan`), which I want to join. They both display the same column names and `arath_scan` is a smaller table which is included in `hmmscan1`. Now I want to select only those entries of `hmmscan1` where a certain column (`domain_name`) of `hmmscan1` and `arath_scan` agree.

I used the following command:

```
SELECT h.auto_inc, 
       h.query_prot_id, 
       h.taxon_schema, 
       h.domain_name 
FROM   hmmscan1 AS h 
       INNER JOIN arath_scan 
               ON h.domain_name = arath_scan.domain_name;
```

The result is that I get more rows than are available at `hmmscan1`, which I acutally wanted to reduce.... So instead of ~10.000 rows I get 500.000 rows with many multiple entries.

Has someone an idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a `group by` .try this

```
    select h.auto_inc,h.query_prot_id,h.taxon_schema, h.domain_name 
    from hmmscan1 as h 
    inner join arath_scan on h.domain_name=arath_scan.domain_name
    GROUP BY h.domain_name;
```

**OR** Group by any column you want to be distinct. as `h.query_prot_id`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this particular problem:

select distinct h.query_prot_id, h.taxon_schema, h.prot_id, h.domain_name from arath_scan a, hmmscan1 h where a.query_prot_id = h.query_prot_id and a.domain_name = h.domain_name;

I had to use the distinct option and two restrictions in the where clause.